# CMakeLists using variables to define source/include locations

Tags: cmake

I have an AndroidStudio project with 'C' files in.  I can compile and run as-is.

My native files are in

- src/main/jni/aes
- src/main/jni/libjpeg
- src/main/jni/smuglib

I am trying to move the source to a location external to the Android studio project so that I can use it from several locations/projects to avoid copy/paste/mistake cycle.

I have defined the include path in CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(src/main/jni/aes src/main/jni/libjpeg src/main/jni/smuglib)
```

And have specified the files in the add_library command

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
            src/main/jni/aes/aes.c
            src/main/jni/smuglib/smuglib.c
.... etc
```

**How do I set up a variable to refer to these paths, eg 'src/main/jni/aes'  so that I can use it in both the include and in the source list?**

I tried variations on 
    set(aes_src, src/main/jni/aes)

but uses of it as ${aes_src} either in the include path statement or in the source list give me all sorts of arcane errors which I am at a loss to understand.

I will generate some of these and include them if folk think it would help, but I am likely barking up the wrong kettle of fish with this approach.

**Is there a better approach?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `set(VAR_NAME item1 item2 item3)`. No commas needed.